# While adding Objects to object repository in QTP, it does not get correct object class, why?

Tags: object, repository, qtp

In order to test the Login functionality of a web application using QTP, I try to add objects (username, password and login button) to object repository with application opened in IE. While i click on username and Password objects to add, it should get them as WebEdit class objects but somehow QTP gets another object name as WebElement class. I am sure that i click on the correct place on page. I could not figure out where the problem is?

Comment: What is the version of QTP, IE and what is the technology that you are testing?

Comment: I am using IE version 11.0.21 and QTP version 12.0 (UFT) and I am testing Java technology.

Comment: What are the add-ins that you are loading? Is it possible to share the html? Its hard to find root cause.

Comment: Add-ins i am loading are ActiveX, Visual Basics and Web in UFT. I am not able to share html here.

Comment: Try to add those objects to OR manually I mean using "Define new test object" in OR.

Comment: Yeah, It did work manually.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.learnqtp.com/uft-object-identification-tips/

Zoom level of Application page in IE was not appropriate.That's why QTP did not sense correct object. Found the issue and that was very simple thing.